# Web3.js dist folder missing after installation

Tags: npm

i am following a tutorial to learn how to create smart contract with ethereum and solidity. Now i have to install the web3.js package using npm and that's the syntax command i used:

```
npm install ethereum/web3.js --save
```

But when i look at the dir structure inside the node_modules/web3 i have the following folders but i haven't the dist folder:

- assets
- docs
- packages

I tried googling before posting here but I haven't found a solution and instead I found lots of people have same problem..

the version npm installed was:

- web3@1.0.0
- web3@1.0.0-beta.49

Any hint or suggestion is really appreciated